# Writing a .bat file to find a filename in an ASCII file and setting it as a variable

Tags: batch-file

I want to extract the filename from a line of my ascii file. In a line of the file examplefile.txt, I have I have the following text:

```
Inputfile  input_file.txt
Outputfile output_file.txt
```

What I want to do is open examplefile.txt and read the name of the input and output files and set them up as a variable. The equivalent of the following line:

```
Set "INPUTFILE=input_file.txt"
Set "OUTPUTFILE=output_file.txt"
```

I've tried something like this, which is not working:

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in (examplefile.txt) do (
set "TEMP=%%A"
if %TEMP% = "Inputfile" goto :break
)
:break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks good until the `for /f`, but I'd probably just use

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in (examplefile.txt) do set "%%A=%%B"
```

After that you should have your two variables `%inputfile%` and `%outputfile%`.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the performance if you use FINDSTR to filter out the unwanted lines.

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ('findstr /r /c:"^Inputfile " /c:"^Outputfile " "examplefile.txt"') do set "%%A=%%B"
```

Comment: Assuming that the file contains more than those two lines. The question is a bit fuzzy on that (as are sadly most questions on potentially important prerequisites).